# How set icon for ClickOnce

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Tried example for set icon in ClickOnce installation, but get no progress. In publish->Options->File Associations set extension for .application and selected my icon. Maybe i looking for wrong way to set icon, but my app.appref-ms still have default icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context menu on project-> Properties -> Tab Application -> TextBox Icon

Comment: This is set icon for application .exe, but i need to set icon for ClickOnce .appref-ms

Comment: @Archi.Moore Check the resolution of the icon. It is 256x256? What is the OS version?

Comment: @kennyzx Our resolution is 32x32 pixel.

Comment: Actually setting this icon also sets the .appref-ms icon. And I just try a 32x32 ico with a new Windows Forms project on win10, it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, u was right. I got icon size 48x48. When i changed size for 32x32 it started work. Thanks soo much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the app, source: [ClickOnce start menu icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645570/clickonce-start-menu-icon). There are many solutions provided by the contributers of the aforementioned source, some indicating that it might be in the size of the icon.ico file or that the file wasn't marked included prior to the deployment. Hopefully you'll find your answer there.

Comment: Yes, i tried all variants that found in google, but didt get correct.

Comment: Have you by any chance checked this Stackoverflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152188/can-i-create-a-desktop-icon-for-a-clickonce-application. There is a mention of having to add a bit of code to accomplish an icon change for the ClickOnce app's appref-ms