# ClickOnce not showing application Icon on taskbar win 10

Tags: icons, clickonce

My clickonce application is not showing the icon on the taskbar that I have setup in Visual studio.  It shows it correctly when I run the application, but when not running the "pinned" icon shows blank.  I'm understanding this is blank icon is probably that of the .appref-ms file which is a blank icon.  But it is really annoying when I pin one of my applications that the icon is blank.  This was not a problem in windows 7, but windows 10 it is as I have recently updated to.

Has anyone experienced this and what did you do to get to your clickonce application to show its icon when pinned to the taskbar of windows 10?
See pictures.

My taskbar showing the not running, but pinned applications.

taskbar - no icon

[image: taskbar - no icon]

This is the folder I believe this pin is references which has blank Icon (file type .appref-ms)

Start menu folder - no icon

[image: Start menu folder - no icon]

My start menu shows the correct icons for the applications.

Start menu - icon

[image: Start menu - icon]

EDIT: I'm also noticing that when I pin my clickonce program to the taskbar, it is not running the "Check for updates before the application starts" for clickonce.  Instead, it seems it is running the local .exe file found in the clickonce folders on the computer.  So this means when the app launches it no longer checks for updates because it isn't a network deployed version running.

Comment: I reduced the icon dimension to 32x32 as noted here and will give it some time.  When uninstalled the app and reinstalled it worked.  But I think that has previously only temporarily fixed the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872862/how-set-icon-for-clickonce